# Freeradius: Clients.conf and CoA

Tags: freeradius

I am on Freeradius 3.0.15

When i add my client (NAS IP) in `clients.conf` my configuration of the CoA is perfect, working fine without any problem.

The issue is my clients list should come from the database but not this file. I add the client in my nas table and during the server startup i see the message

```
rlm_sql (sql): Executing select query: SELECT id, nasname, shortname, type, secret, server FROM nas
rlm_sql (sql): Adding client 192.168.0.12 (myNAS) to global clients list
rlm_sql (192.168.0.12): Client "myNAS" (sql) added
```

But when I send a CoA request i get the message

```
WARNING: Unknown destination 192.168.0.12:3799 for CoA request.
```

I am looking for a solution where i can have clients listed only in `database` but not in the `clients.conf` file.

Any thoughts??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a reply from other forum that it is not possible in v3

http://lists.freeradius.org/pipermail/freeradius-users/2017-August/088480.html